# Ice is in alcohol, if the ice melts does fluid level go up, down or stay the same?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

The answer key says fluid level goes down. So, I understand the the ice would sink since density of alcohol is less than ice. However, I remember that when ice is in water and it melts, the water level would stay the same, that's why I thought it would be the same for this question. What is different about this that the fluid level actually decreases?

Comment: "However, I remember that when ice is in water and it melts, the water level would stay the same, that's why I thought it would be the same for this question." - Do you remember the reasoning for why the water level stays the same? If not, then review that case.

Comment: Yes, it was because the amount of fluid displaced before the ice sinked was the same as the amount of fluid displaced after. However, I still don't know how it would decrease if I applied the same concept to ice in alcohol

Comment: Hint: Do you remember why ice floats in water?

Answer (score 1):

If the ice melts in water , there is no change in the water level.
BUT

If you had solid alcohol floating in water, when it melts, the level would drop, because water and alcohol mix at the molecular level; i.e. water filling spaces among alcohol molecules.

Same will be applied in the case given in the problem.

Comment: Please don't append "thank you, vote if you liked" to all your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Ice will sink and melt and upon melting it converts to water which has a higher density than ice . Mass can't change so if density increases than volume will decrease and level will go down . In case of ice and water ice is less dense than water and floats and replaces same mass of water .